# Can't retrieve text string from file After Effects/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I'm trying to pull text from file using a JS extension:

```
try{
    myPath = "c:\source.txt";
    $.evalFile(myPath);
    eval(thisComp.name)[0];
}catch(err){
    "MISSING";
}
```

Those are the strings in the source.txt file:

```
var comp1 = ["Text 0", "Text 1", "Text 2"];
var comp2 = ["Text 0", "Text 1", "Text 2"];
var comp3 = ["Text 0", "Text 1", "Text 2"];
```

It worked on my PC but not on my workstation.

Comment: Does `c:` exist on your workstation?

Comment: yes, It does exist.